# how to get the actual dimensions of the element displayed in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

As you can see in the image the dimension is `388 x 274.83`

but, when console the things
`console.log(e.offsetWidth,e.offsetHeight,e.getBoundingClientRect())` the values I got which is different.

The html looks like this with applied transform

```
<div id="element" style="width: 360px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1.07778, 0, 0, 1.07778, 0, 0);">
```

```
<div id="content" class="sidebar__content p-2" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
  <div class="bg-E4E4E4 segmentaion-viewer p-2 " id="elementContainer" style="filter: brightness(100%) contrast(1) saturate(1);" tabindex="0">
    <div id="element" style="width: 360px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1.07778, 0, 0, 1.07778, 0, 0);">
      <div class="imageNameStyle">cado1.jpg</div>
      <div class="segment-annotator-outer-container" id="imgOuterContainer" style="width: 360px; height: 255px;">
        <div id="segmentContainer" class="segment-annotator-inner-container" style="width: 360px; height: 255px;">
          <svg id="svgHook" style="pointer-events: none;"></svg>
          <canvas width="360" height="255" class="segment-annotator-layer image-layer" id="canvasLayer"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
onload: function () { // onload of image
 let h = document.getElementById("element")
 console.log(h.scrollWidth,h.scrollHeight,h.getBoundingClientRect())
}
```

Anyone knows **how to get the actual dimensions of the element displayed in viewport?**

Comment: simply try `document.getElementById('element').width` ?

Comment: @aflyzer don't know why it is undefined...

Comment: could you please give complete code you're using ? in a snippet code

Comment: @aflyzer copy paste will not work I need to recreate the problem. but take a look at html

Comment: Can't repro, when do you call the JS?

Comment: @Kaiido on load of image I have updated that code. have a look

Comment: With your JS you are measuring `<div id="element">`, with the dev-tools you are measuring `<canvas width="360" height="255" class="segment-annotator-layer image-layer" id="canvasLayer">` Why should these be the same size?

Comment: @Kaiido look at height why i'm getting 295 instead of 255 then? coz I applied transform something happened I'm checking that but not getting.

Comment: But once again, you're not looking at the same element. The container can be smaller than its content, this is no magic.

Comment: @Kaiido finally I cannot get the actual value. that's it right!

Answer (score 0):

The .getBoundingClientRect() method should do the magic... try to pay attention to the transformation matrix css attribute... because probably you call the console.log() before the style is being applied.

In alternative to .getBoundingCLientRect() you could use something like:

```
    var element = document.getElementById(/* your element id */);   //or use a different selector
    var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);

    
    var effective_height =  element.clientHeight + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingTop) + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingBottom) + parseFloat(computedStyle.marginTop) + parseFloat(computedStyle.marginBottom);
    var effective_width =  element.clientWidth + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingRight) + parseFloat(computedStyle.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(computedStyle.marginRight) + parseFloat(computedStyle.marginLeft);

    //an alternative

    var effective_height =  element.scrollHeight;
    var effective_width =  element.scrollWidth;
```

Comment: You don't wanna take care about margin niether padding just remove them from the sum and ignore the computedStyle variable.

Comment: wrong! i got `295 360` height and width

Comment: Try using the alternative option. I just edited the answer.

Comment: I already went through this document, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements. nothing worked

Comment: i update the answer...  .getBoundingClientRect() method should do the magic... try to pay attention to the transformation matrix css attribute... because probably you call the console.log() before the style is being applied. To be sure about it try to insert `let h = document.getElementById("element")
 console.log(h.scrollWidth,h.scrollHeight,h.getBoundingClientRect())` directly in the browser console.

Comment: no use, `let h = document.getElementById("hook");console.log(h.offsetWidth,h.clientWidth, h.clientWidth, h.offsetHeight,h.getBoundingClientRect())
VM1900882:1 360 360 360 295 DOMRect {x: 61, y: 134, width: 388, height: 317.9444580078125, top: 134, …}`

Comment: as you can see the getBoundingClientRect() get the right dimensions use h.getBoundingClientRect().width and h.getBoundingClientRect().height to get only what you need...   h.getBoundingClientRect().height is a little bit higher of the "Canvas" element probably because there are margins or padding inside of the child elements of "#element"

Comment: ok, it seems those values we cannot get. np I'll work with approximate values only.